# How do I make an SKNode follow an SKShapeNode in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a line, lets say a rounded rect, drawn on screen (SKShapeNode drawn from a CGPath). Now I want a node to follow that rounded rect, either clockwise or counter clockwise. I've done this with SKAction's followPath:asOffset:orientToPath:duration: method, which works fine if the node starts at the path's origin.

The thing is, the node can be placed anywhere on the rounded rect, and when I press and hold a button I want it to start following the rect from the point it's currently located. When I release the button the node stops where it is. Right now if I stop the node and start it again it follows a new rounded rect starting at the nodes point.

Is there an easy way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may make use of newly introduced SKConstraint class (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKConstraint_Ref/).

For a quick introduction take a look at session 606 from WWDC2014: "What's new in SpriteKit".

It's really quick and simple way to adjust position/rotation/distance of the sprite in relation to another sprite.

What you exactly need is

```
  + (instancetype)orientToNode:(SKNode *)node
                     offset:(SKRange *)radians
```

Comment: It might be possible to do something with this, will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult problem. I can think of two solutions:

1. Each time you press and hold, construct a new CGPath for the node to follow which starts at the point your node is currently stopped.
2. Keep a reference to the SKAction object that you're running. When you stop pressing on the screen, instead of stopping the action, set it's `speed` property to `0.0`. This will effectively pause the animation. When you press down again, set the speed back to 1.0.

Comment: This works great as long as it keeps moving in the same direction. Setting speed to -1 does not seem to work, so I assume I have to construct a new CGPath each time the direction changes?

Comment: You could use `-[SKAction reversedAction]`, but that would start you at the beginning going the other direction.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. So I guess the only option is to construct a new path every time or come up with a completely different approach.